# C++ XML comments to generate MSDN style CHM

Tags: c++, documentation, msdn, chm

I have several projects, some using managed code and some using only unmanaged. All have the XML comments have been added and the XML documentation is being generated correctly (the generated xml file and intermediate the xdc files).

Surely there's something that can take these files (the output of xdcmake) and generate MSDN style chm help! ?
From what I understand, both doxygen and sandcastle ignore that obvious step and re-invent the wheel to re-scan your code. (there's also the fact that sandcastle is apparently useless for non-.NET projects).

Having tried doxygen (horrible output, but fast) and sandcastle (nice MSDN style output, but sloooooow) both are begging to be outdone by something much simpler.

It would also be nice if there was some kind of editor associated that we can also write the 'Getting Started' and 'Information' kind of pages that are also needed with any API documentation.

Does anyone know of any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try [DoxyComment](http://doxycomment.sourceforge.net/). Here is the description from Doxygen's [Helper tools & scripts](http://www.doxygen.nl/helpers.html):

> An addin for Visual Studio 2005 called
>   DoxyComment was created by Troels
>   Gram. It is designed to assist you in
>   inserting context sensitive comment
>   blocks into C/C++ source files.
>   DoxyComment also comes with an xslt
>   template that lets you generate
>   documentation like the MSDN library.

Comment: I've had a quick look at this in the past, maybe I should give it another go. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, Sandcastle is your best bet. I know it can be a bit of a pain to configure, but the documentation is exactly the style you are looking for.

Comment: Sandcastle, as far as I know, doesn't work with unmanaged projects. Is there a way to make them work?

Answer (score 0):

I know the project where people still use [NDocConsole](http://ndoc.sourceforge.net/content/consoleapplication.htm)

However I suppose that NDoc is a dead project, because on http://ndoc.sourceforge.net/ there are no updates since 2005